# Putting in the correct form of the verb - go versus have gone

Tags: modal-verbs, semi-modals

I'm practicing modals, and in an exercise I had to fill in the correct form of the verb:

> We couldn't _______ (go) to the concert anyway as Jamie wasn't very well.

I put in ‘go’ but the correct answer turns out to be ‘have gone’. The sentence was by itself. What's the intuition for that?

Comment: 'Couldn't have' expresses past impossibility of an idea being true. Anyway is the clue, expressing finality.

Comment: Not a very good exercise, as I can imagine circumstances in which someone might say either of those. "The concert was cancelled at the last minute because the soloist was ill, but we couldn't have gone anyway... " [even if it had gone ahead]. "I'm sorry you weren't able to get to the concert [where we had planned to meet], but we couldn't go anyway...".

Comment: Kate - But, we know it's an exercise "practicing modals", and therefore probably not a time when someone might say the first. :p    But yeah, both are "correct" in the sense of "sound like grammatical, intelligible English".

Comment: I'm not sure there's *ever* a difference between these two in modern, colloquial English (though they are technically different tenses).   Can anyone think of an example where one is appropriate and the other is not?